# Base internationalization on but still show the base language as option

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

There's something that I still can't understand about localizations on iOS.

I have this situation, with base internationalization on and I added italian language:

[image]

So Xcode clearly sees that the development language is english. So why if I localize a file I see english as option?

[image]

I mean if Xcode knows that the base localization is english why I can still choose english?